# Template a member variable in a class

Tags: c++, templates, architecture, crtp

I am doing some refactoring on some older/messy code. I am trying to improve things little by little. Because it fit the project, I started implementing CRTP (for static polymorphism)  on some class, let's call it `sensor`. Through CRTP, there is now a `real` and a `fake` implementation.

Now, I am trying to put templates in a class (`interface_actions`) that uses `sensor`. I arrived at something like that:

```cpp
class interface_actions
{
public:
    template <class implementation>
    interface_actions(sensor<implementation> detector)
    : _detector(detector)
    {}

    // Lots of stuff that I don't want to touch

private:
#if (SOMETHING)
    sensor<real> _detector;
#else
    sensor<fake> _detector;
#endif
};
```

As you can see, I did not know what to do with `_detector` without having to make the entire class a template, so I used the preprocessor ...

This is more of an architectural question I guess, but how would you go about making `_detector` take sensor without making the entire class a template?
It seems to me that I would have to fundamentally rewrite this part of the code, but maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: Is using "real" polymorphism an option ? If so you could make `sensor` an interface/base class with `fake` and `real` derived implementations.

Comment: You could make the entire class template, but provide default template value to avoid writing it explicitly in production code. Sth like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/a3bK1zbrr).

Comment: What is "something", exactly? It all hinges on what it actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
class interface_actions
{
    std::conditional_t<SOMETHING, sensor<real>, sensor<fake>> _detector;
};
```

if `SOMETHING` yields `true`, `_detector` will be of type `sensor<real>`, `sensor<fake>` otherwise.

but this only works if `SOMETHING` is outside of the scope of  `class interface_actions`, otherwise you have to make the class take a template. As pptaszni suggested you could make a default template parameter to "hide" the template argument, so your old code that says `interface_actions object;` won't be affected:

```
template<bool is_real = true>
class interface_actions
{
    std::conditional_t<is_real, sensor<real>, sensor<fake>> _detector;
};


int main() {
    interface_actions foo;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo._detector), sensor<real>>);
}
```